# Eigenvalues of $X$ in the metric of $Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

What does this statement describe? $X$ and $Y$ are matrices.

> The eigenvalues of $X$ in the metric of $Y$.

I've not seen this language used before in this fashion and I don't really know what taking the eigenvalues of a matrix in the metric of another matrix means.

Could someone decipher this for me?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: In a signal processing paper, this one specifically: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1143830&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D1143830 sorry for only having a closed garden link.

Comment: Thanks for the context, though I cannot actually read the paper. But I hope my answer still makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it's an old paper (although still highly useful), so there aren't a lot of sources, only that one that I found :/. It describes a fairly famous algorithm called MUSIC which is used for finding the angle of arrival of a wireless signal, among other things.

Comment: Actually, there's an extensive wikipedia page on it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_signal_classification

Comment: hi Ethan can you explain how you related the above answer to the MUSIC algorithm??

Comment: @aishwaryamekala this language is used in the paper that first presented the MUSIC algorithm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means the $\lambda$ such that $X - \lambda Y$ is not invertible. The usual eigenvalues are those where $Y$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: That makes perfect sense in the context it's used! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Ethan So in modern terms it is the spectrum of the matrix pencil $(X,Y)$.